# How to use Resultset rs.next() multiple times in a single jdbc class using java jdbc?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, multiple-resultsets

I have a database with two fields orderid,flow.

Orderid field will be having n number of orderid integers.

flow field will be having 7 strings ,to categorize the order id belongs to this flow.

Now i want to categorize all the orderid fields according to the flow type.

I have written code with multiple sql statements in my java jdbc class.

when i run the code I am getting results for my first result set sql query but not for my second result set sql query.

I use two separate result set and below are my snippet.

can any one help me to achieve this?

Thank you.

```
package com;


import java.sql.*;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;
import com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException;
public class getOrderinfo
{
 static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
 static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://10.10.10.14/opsbank-ii";
 static final String USER = "root";
 static final String PASS = "p@ssw0rd";
 public static int row_count=0;
 public static int count_for_totalfiles=0;
 public static String filename_allocated=""; 
 public static String dateofcar_allocated="";
 public String row_data="";
 public static int orderid=0;
 public static int[] orderid_sto=new int[15000];
 public static int[] orderid_ABPEL=new int[15000];
 public static int[] orderid_WBPG=new int[15000];
 public static int[] orderid_sto2=new int[15000];
 public static String flow="";
 public static String[] flow_sto=new String[15000];
 public static String[] flow_ABPEL=new String[15000];
 public static String[] flow_WBPG=new String[15000]; 
 public static String[] flow_sto2=new String[15000];
 public static Date dateofprocessing;
 public static Date[] dateofprocessing_sto=new Date[15000];
 public static Date[] dateofprocessing_sto2=new Date[15000];
 public static Date[] dateofprocessing_WBPG=new Date[15000];
 public static String Filename_ret0="";
 public static String  Filename_ret_ABPEL="";
 public static String Filename_ret_WBPG="";
 public static String Filename0_all="";
 public static String Filename0_all_ABPEL="";
 public static String Filename0_all_WBPG="";

 public static String Filenameafterlastchar0="";
 public static String Filenameafterlastchar0_ABPEL="";
 public static String Filenameafterlastchar0_WBPG="";



 public static void main(String args[]) throws SQLTimeoutException
 {


  //public static void main(String[] args) 


  Connection conn = null;
 Statement stmt = null,stmt1=null;



  try{
 //STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

  Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Enter the Date(Format : 2016-02-22) ");

  String date = scanner.next();

  SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
  Date date2=null;
  /* try {
    //Parsing the String
    date2 = (Date) dateFormat.parse(date);
  } 
  catch (ParseException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
  }*/


 System.out.println("Input Date:"+date);

 //STEP 3: Open a connection
 System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
 conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);

 //STEP 4: Execute a query
 System.out.println("Creating statement...");
 stmt = conn.createStatement();
 stmt1=conn.createStatement();
 String sql,sql_WBPG;

 sql = "select orderid,flow,dateofprocessing from orderinfo where     
 ordertype='CAR' and dateofprocessing like '%"+date+"%'and flow='ABPEL'";
 sql_WBPG = "select orderid,flow,dateofprocessing from 
  orderinfo where    
 ordertype='CAR' and dateofprocessing like '%"+date+"%'and flow='WBPG'";

         ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);


 //STEP 5: Extract data from result set
            System.out.println("For WBPG:\n");

  System.out.println("-----------------------
 ---------------------------------------\n");

  while(rs.next()){
    int i=0;

   orderid_sto[i]=rs.getInt("orderid");
   flow_sto[i]=rs.getString("flow");
   dateofprocessing_sto[i]=rs.getDate("dateofprocessing");
   // System.out.println("Order ID get : "+orderid);
   // orderid_sto[i]=orderid;
   // System.out.println("Order ID After storing : "+orderid_sto[i]);

   //  flow_sto[i++]=flow;

   // dateofprocessing_sto[i++]=dateofprocessing;

    System.out.println("orderid :"+orderid_sto[i]+" || Flow :    
   "+flow_sto[i]+" || date : "+dateofprocessing_sto[i]);    
     //  System.out.println(orderid_sto[i]);    
      i++;
      row_count++;
      count_for_totalfiles++;


      Filename_ret0="'"+rs.getInt("orderid")+"',";
     Filename0_all=Filename0_all+Filename_ret0;


   //Display values
   //System.out.print("BOOKISSID: " + BOOKISSID);
   //System.out.print(", ISSN: " + ISSN);
   //System.out.println("\n");


   }
    System.out.println("Total Number of CAR orders found for the date :       "+date2+" = "+row_count);
   //after removing the comma
   if (Filename0_all.length() > 0 &&     
   Filename0_all.charAt(Filename0_all.length()-1)==',') 
  {
    Filenameafterlastchar0 = Filename0_all.substring(0, 
  Filename0_all.length()-1);
  }
  else
  {
    System.out.println("comma not found as last character :1 ");
  }

 System.out.println("combined name after comma removal :1    
 :"+Filenameafterlastchar0);





  System.out.println("For WBPG:\n");
  System.out.println("-------------------------------
  -------------------------------\n");


  ResultSet rs_WBPG=stmt1.executeQuery(sql_WBPG);

   while(rs_WBPG.next())
  {
    int j=0;
    orderid_WBPG[j]=rs_rs_WBPG.getInt("orderid");
    flow_WBPG[j]=rs_rs_WBPG.getString("flow");


          Filename_ret_WBPG="'"+rs.getInt("orderid")+"',";
         Filename0_all_WBPG=Filename0_all_WBPG+Filename_ret_WBPG;

        System.out.println("orderid :"+orderid_WBPG[j]+" || Flow : 
  "+flow_WBPG[j]+" || date : "+dateofprocessing_WBPG[j]);   


   }

   //after removing the comma for ABPEL
   if (Filename0_all_WBPG.length() > 0 && 
   Filename0_all_WBPG.charAt(Filename0_all_WBPG.length()-1)==',') 
   {
    Filenameafterlastchar0_WBPG = Filename0_all_WBPG.substring(0, 
   Filename0_all_WBPG.length()-1);
    }
   else
    {
     System.out.println("comma not found as last character :1 ");
     }

    System.out.println("combined name after comma removal for ABPEL:1 
    :"+Filenameafterlastchar0_WBPG);




    //STEP 6: Clean-up environment

    rs.close();
     rs_WBPG.close();
     stmt.close();
    conn.close();
  }

  catch(SQLTimeoutException ste)
   {
   System.out.println("\nSQL Time out Error...");
    System.out.println("\nplease Restart the services...");
     ste.printStackTrace();
   }

   catch(MySQLSyntaxErrorException mysqlerr)
   {
    System.out.println("date issue");
   }
   catch(SQLException se){
   //Handle errors for JDBC
    se.printStackTrace();
    }catch(Exception e){
     //Handle errors for Class.forName
    e.printStackTrace();
   }

   finally{
   //finally block used to close resources
    try{
      if(stmt!=null)
          stmt.close();
    }catch(SQLException se2){
    }// nothing we can do
    try{
       if(conn!=null)
          conn.close();
    }catch(SQLException se){
     se.printStackTrace();
     }//end finally try
     }//end try



 }//end main
 }//end FirstExample
```

end of snippet.

below is are Error getting after changes from while(!rs_WBPG.next()) to (rs_WBPG.next())

```
java.sql.SQLException: After end of result set
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1074)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:988)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:974)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:919)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.checkRowPos(ResultSetImpl.java:854)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getInt(ResultSetImpl.java:2709)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getInt(ResultSetImpl.java:2850)
at com.getOrderinfo.main(getOrderinfo.java:162)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show the minimum code necessary to reproduce your problem. Your current code contains to many unrelated things and is badly formatted which makes it hard to follow.

Comment: Your use of `while(!rs_WBPG.next())` does not make any sense. You need to remove the `!`.

Comment: @ Mark Rotteveel : sorry for the inconvenience.i have updated the code as per your guide lines.but it throws an error as : java.sql.SQLException: After end of result set.
kindly help me sir

Comment: @ Mark Rotteveel   dear sir,kindly help me sir.I have updated my current code with the error details

Comment: You have done almost nothing to your code; it is still poorly formatted and contains too much code that is not directly related to the problem at hand. As to the error, it happens because you call `rs.getInt()` instead of `rs_WBPG.getInt()` as already indicated in the answer by Eran.

Answer (score 0):

You reset your `i` index to `0` inside the loop, so you only assign values to the first element of each array.

Change:

```
while (rs.next()) {
    int i = 0;
    ...
    i++;
}
```

to:

```
int i = 0;
while (rs.next()) {
    ...
    i++;
}
```

EDIT:

Your second loop should be :

```
int j = 0;
while(rs_WBPG.next()) {
    ...
    orderid_WBPG[j]=rs_WBPG.getInt("orderid");
    ...
    j++;
}
```

Comment: sorry sir.CHANGED MADE AS PER YOUR GUIDANCE.butstill i am getting no results for the second loop.

Comment: @ eran kindly request you to help me

Comment: @IlavarasanJayaraman I don't understand what you are trying to do with the second loop. Your `while(!rs_WBPG.next())` means it will only be entered if `rs_WBPG` doesn't have any rows, and inside the loop you are attempting to read from the other ResultSet, which you already read from in the first loop.

Comment: @ eran : sir for you kind information re_WBPG.next() should be having my secon sql query results and it has the rows and columns in database.please help.thank you for ur valuable time

Comment: @ eran sir: chnges made.But still no results but run time error.kindly have look on my edit.I am getting error as "java.sql.SQLException: After end of result set " .Kindly help.

Comment: @IlavarasanJayaraman The second loop should access `rs_WBPG`, not `rs`. That's your problem.

Comment: @ eran :  I have updated the code to rs_WBPG.but now it shows a run time error as : java.sql.SQLException: After end of result set.Complete stack trace on my edit.kindly help me sir

Comment: @ eran : Kindly request you to help me sir .I have updated my current code and details of error.

Answer (score 0):

In the second loop you are using the old rs. use the new rs_WBPG you created.  basically you copy pasted from the 1st loop but didn't changed the values in the loop

```
while(!rs_WBPG.next())
  {
    int j=0;
    orderid_WBPG[j]=rs_WBPG.getInt("orderid");
    flow_WBPG[j]=rs_WBPG.getString("flow");


          Filename_ret_WBPG="'"+rs_WBPG.getInt("orderid")+"',";
         Filename0_all_WBPG=Filename0_all_WBPG+Filename_ret_WBPG;

        System.out.println("orderid :"+orderid_WBPG[j]+" || Flow : 
  "+flow_WBPG[j]+" || date : "+dateofprocessing_WBPG[j]);   


   }
```

Comment: @ sambi reddy : Thank you for your golden time sir.Kindly guide me which value needs change.i hope i already done all changes for second loop except from while(! rs_WBPG.next()) to while( rs_WBPG.next()).but it throws error.kindly have look on my edit and please help me sir

Comment: you should use while(rs_WBPG.next()) not while(!rs_WBPG.next())

Comment: @ sambi reddy : Thank you sir,But After changing this code ,it throws as error as : java.sql.SQLException: After end of result set.

Comment: :The complete stack trace has been updated on my subject.Kindly request you to help me sir.

Comment: @ sambi Reddy : I have updated the current code.Kindly help me sir.